# android changing button background at main UI from an Intent

Tags: android, background, android-intent, gallery

Basically, I want to try changing a button's background at main interface, but I want it done from an intent. So, for example I have this main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20px">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tunein"
                android:layout_width="125px"
                android:layout_height="125px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20px"
                android:background="@drawable/tunein"
                >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="125px"
                android:layout_height="125px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20px"
                android:background="@drawable/settings">
            </Button>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20px">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="125px"
                android:layout_height="125px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20px"
                android:background="@drawable/sharing">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="125px"
                android:layout_height="125px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_margin="20px">
            </Button>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then if the button with id 'profile' is clicked, an intent shows up and it will show a gallery with images from SDCARD and when user clicks one of the image, the 'profile' button's background will change....

how to do it...??? THX for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In button onclick you just call the code for gallery images to display like

```
Button profile=(Button)findviewbyid(R.id.profile);
profile.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(

public void onclick(View v)
 //call code for displaying images  from gallery
));
```

then after returning from gallery you will get image-path from that image path you can place the image in button

Comment: can it be done from that?? I mean, intent that change one of main layout's element.... if press back, will the image be reverted back to its default image ??